# Reason for Kitaev chain Pfaffian being calculated in momentum space

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-phase

In Kitaev's paper where [Kitaev](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440) defines his toy model for observation of Majorana fermions (MFs), he suggests a method of determining whether a system contain MFs at it ends. This method is to calculate the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of the Hamiltonian in an antisymmetric basis, whereby the sign of the pfaffian is connected with the topological state.

Kitaev then goes on to do this for a Hamiltonian in momentum space, and justifies using only the points $k=\{0,\pi\}$.

I am just curious as to whether it is possible to instead use the real space basis to calculate the Pfaffian for this system (after applying the appropriate basis transformation to get my Hamiltonian into a skew symmetric form, as per the requisites of the Pfaffian), and if not, what the limitation is. It seems to me that there should be no difference in the result of the Pfaffian.